# ReactJS - Cannot read property 'location' of undefined at new Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So I have a pretty basic setup for my `index.js` file, where all my routes are held. I'm getting the above `TypeError` from the console, but I'm unsure as to why. Below is my code:

```js
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

// React router goodies
import { Router, Route, browserHistory, IndexRoute, hashHistory } from 'react-router';

const App = require('./components/App.jsx');

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history = {browserHistory}> 
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Could it be the spaces around the equals sign?

Comment: try 
`import { APP } from './components/App.jsx');`

or 

`<Route path="/" component={App}/>`

Comment: Which version of RR are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 4.0.0, which I believe is the latest?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`browserHistory` is no more supported from [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) version 4, here is the issue raised - [Can no longer import { IndexRoute, browserHistory } from version 4.](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4732)

Either switch to version `3.0.0` or use [BrowserRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter) to fix the same.

**For version `3.0.0` :**

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.1",
    "react-router": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
}
```

**For version `4.0.0`:**

```
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = require('./components/App.jsx');

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter> 
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
    </Route>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```